# Is the SHA256 value in the bitcoin address wiki accurate?

Tags: sha256, address-generation

From the wiki page https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses the example of "How to Create Bitcoin Address" shows the SHA256 of:

0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6

to be

600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408

If I use this online tool http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator

I get: 32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're treating the pubkey as string data. What you need to do is treat it as raw binary hexadecimal. If you use [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?hex=0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6) and calculate it using Binary Hash hex bytes you do indeed get `600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408`.

Comment: Ah, of course. Rookie mistake! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

actually the public key:

`0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6`

is hex string, so you need transform it to bytes before you calculate the correct value.

You can use Python3 to get the correct value:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> public_key_hexstr = '0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6'
>>> public_key_bytes = bytes.fromhex(public_key_hexstr)
>>> hashlib.sha256(public_key_bytes).hexdigest()
'600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408'
```

Or you can install bx tool in macOS using brew:

```
$ brew install bx
```

then:

```
$ bx sha256 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6
600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408
```

Answer (score 0):

ASCII-encoded hex strings are easily handled by [Bitcoin-Explorer](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki).  The following recreates results from [en.bitcoin.it](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses) properly:

`% echo -n 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6 | bx base16-decode | shasum -a 256`
**600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408  -**

`% echo 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6 | bx sha256`

**600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408**

`% echo 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6 | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | bx base58check-encode -v 0`

**16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM**

`% echo 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6 | bx ec-to-address -v 0`
**16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM**